# Diferencia entre variable de sesión y variable de aplicación visual

Tags: visual

Quiero saber

¿cual es la diferencia exacta que hay entre ambas cosas?

Comment: Bienvenid@ al sitio, recuerda revisar [ask] que te brinda información de como realizar preguntas en el sitio, estas sean bien recibidas y además obtengas la ayuda requerida, te sugerimos modificar el formato de tu pregunta agrega lo que investigaste o trataste. No olvides realizar el [tour] del sitio,  saludos.

Comment: Estas hablando de una aplicacion web?

Comment: Si, estamos trabajando paginas, portales y sitios web.

Answer (score 0):

mira cuando tu inicias tu aplicación en el servidor las variables de Application se levantan y tienen el mismo valor en todo tu sitio y para cualquier usuario. Las variables de Session dependen del usuario que inicia en su cuenta (en su sesión) y aunque tengan el mismo nombre será distinta para todos los usuarios.